# Square of any determinant is symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra

This property is given in my book.
The square of any determinant is a symmetric determinant.
Well it works when I take a determinant say $3 \times 3$ and multiply it by itself using row to row multiplication.
But it fails if I multiply using row to column.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by symmetric determinant? Usually the determinant is a number.

Comment: I asked this question in other forums also but I didn't get any answer.
I mean by symmetric determinant by exactly symmetric determinant and I don't know what else to say.Here is the post in other forum where many of the details I have already given please have a look
https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/square-of-determinant-is-symmetric.873144/

Answer (score 2):

The question as it now stands asks why "The square of any determinant is a symmetric determinant."

I suspect what you mean is that the square of any determinant is the determinant of a symmetric matrix.  It is the matrix -- not the determinant -- that is symmetric.

If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of the same size, then $\det(AB) = (\det A)(\det B)$.

If $A$ is a square matrix, then $\det(A^\top) = \det A$.

Therefore
\begin{align}
& (\det A)^2 & & (\text{the square of a determinant}) \\[10pt]
= {} & (\det A)(\det(A^\top)) & & (\text{since } \det(A^\top) = \det A) \\[10pt]
= {} & \det(A A^\top) & & (\text{since } (\det A)(\det B) = \det(AB)) \\[10pt]
= {} & \text{the determinant of} \\[-2pt]
& \text{a symmetric matrix} & & (\text{since } AA^\top \text{is symmetric}).
\end{align}

Comment: That does seem like a likely interpretation. On the other hand, any determinant is the determinant of a symmetric (in fact diagonal) matrix.